# Communicate two Ruby on Rails app SSO for talk each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, microservices, single-sign-on, doorkeeper

We are working on a **RoR** platform compound by 3 applications.

An *OAuth Server* implemented with **doorkeeper** and **devise** just for login (users, emails, password, etc...). And two other **RoR** apps, let's called *ONE* and *TWO*

*ONE* and *TWO* use **devise** and **omniauth-oauth2** configured for using *OAuth Server* for login. So we have a successful SSO.

However, we want now to call REST API in both directions *ONE*->*TWO* and *TWO*->*ONE*.

Once a user (Jack) is logged on *ONE* and *TWO* via Oauth, it does not mean that a GET/POST call from Jack on *ONE* is going to be accepted by *TWO*.

What is the best solution for this use case?
Can this be implemented just by doing some configs on Oauth Server?
There is a gem for this specific use case?

Can someone give me some light?

Comment: This is the wrong place for this type of question. Stackoverflow is the place to ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.  Questions about how to implement an entire feature are off topic as they are either soliciting recommendations or simply lead to  opinion based answers (I used X and it worked for me!).  Try something like [/r/rubyonrails](https://www.reddit.com/r/rubyonrails/) which is a discussion forum and not a Q&A site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask